# Using "TAB" instead "ENTER" for auto completion in PYDEV Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, tabs, pydev, enter

Is there a way to change the auto complete options? I want to auto complete in `pydev` if I use <kbd>TAB</kbd> key instead <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key because it's annoying. Everytime I want to jump to a new line, I hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and it completes something for me instead of jumping a line!

Txs

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not really possible to use tab instead of enter to auto-complete in PyDev (nor in Eclipse itself).

So, what I do in these cases is use Shift-Enter to go to a new line: note that in this case, you can press Shift+Enter from any place in your line and it'll mimic a 'go to end of line, press enter' (which is a nice thing for me).

Implementation note: the `'\t'` and `'\r`,`'\n'` cases are actually hard-coded in Eclipse at: `org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.verifyKey(VerifyEvent)` so, to fix that, you'd need a patch which changed that at Eclipse itself (so, if you feel it's worthwhile, create a bug-request in Eclipse itself to ask for that feature).